# how to get image from ip camera and store the image in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

```
    cvcam = cvCreateFileCapture("http://10.17.32.141.jpg");
    cvNamedWindow("Video",1);
    do{
    image = cvQueryFrame(cvcam);
    cvShowImage("Video",image);
```

Hello..I try to get the images from ip camera and try to store it. I'm using the command above but it didn't work. somebody help me:)

Comment: Use search function first! It looks like a duplicate of OpenCV with Network Cameras at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras

Answer (score 0):

The ip address is incorrect. "10.17.32.141" is the address, which should be followed by a slash and some (file)path on the server. The ".jpg" part is a file extension and should be part of the path, not the server.