# MATLAB - capturing video streams (MJPEG, rtsp, mpeg)

Tags: matlab, opencv, stream, rtsp, mjpeg

Has anyone worked with capturing video streams from IP cameras in MATLAB? For example to grab frames in MATLAB from rtsp://10.10.10.10:554/live.sdp (rtsp stream) or from http://x.x.x.x/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi (mjpeg stream). MATLAB's Image Acquisition Toolbox does not currently support this. I found 2 options:
1) using [mmread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8028). However http stream reading is not supported under 64-bit MATLAB or 
2) to write my own C++ function that grabs frames (I use OpenCV library) and then compile it into MATLAB MEX function.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: FYI, this is the answer from MATLAB support."Unfortunately, you are correct that currently the Image Acquisition Toolbox does not support IP cameras.  Regarding workarounds:

1.  If mmread works for you, perhaps it is feasible for you to install a 32-bit MATLAB on your 64-bit machine.

2.  Writing your own MEX driver should be a possible option.

3.  IMREAD is able to obtain frames from IP cameras.  It may be possible to utilize this capability and build a function that constructs the video stream.  Although frame rate may be an issue."

Comment: Frame rate is an issue with IMREAD function in MATLAB - it only grabs single images, but not a stream. I am going the route of compiling my OpenCV C++ code to Matlab mex function. Below is a link to collection and development kit of matlab mex functions for OpenCV library (thanks to Kota Yamaguchi): https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv.

Comment: THANKs for the mexopencv link. I am using the videoio library since 2 years now and was quite pleased with it. It's great but compiling was a hassle. The mexopencv installation was straightforward. The examples are great und the mex library is done in an awesome way. I think I'll switch to mexopencv and opencv right now.

Comment: I recommend you to post the solution you created as an answer, otherwise this question will remain open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I got from MATLAB support:

> Unfortunately, you are correct that currently the Image Acquisition Toolbox does not support IP cameras. Regarding workarounds: 1. If mmread works for you, perhaps it is feasible for you to install a 32-bit MATLAB on your 64-bit machine. 2. Writing your own MEX driver should be a possible option. 3. IMREAD is able to obtain frames from IP cameras. It may be possible to utilize this capability and build a function that constructs the video stream. Although frame rate may be an issue.

I suggest implementing your own Matlab mex function to grab video frames. Here are some pointers to do so:

1. OpenCV library is used to capture video streams from network cameras, see [OpenCV with Network Cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/q/712998/1121420). Each IP camera may have a different API for accessing video streams (i.e. URL address). For example, `http://10.10.10.10/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=800x600&.mjpg`.
2. Below is a link to collection and development kit of matlab mex functions for OpenCV library (thanks to Kota Yamaguchi): https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv. This library makes it easy to convert between OpenCV data types and mxArray. Here's an example:

   ```
   #include "mexopencv.hpp"
   void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                     int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
       {
       // Check arguments
       if (nlhs!=1 || nrhs!=1)
           mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("myfunc:invalidArgs", "Wrong number of arguments");

       // Convert MxArray to cv::Mat
       cv::Mat mat = MxArray(prhs[0]).toMat();

       // Do whatever you want

       // Convert cv::Mat back to mxArray*
       plhs[0] = MxArray(mat);
   }
   ```
3. The application can be made asynchronous by using threads, where producer thread grabs frames from the camera and puts it into a circular buffer. Consumer thread, on the other hand, retrieves frames from the buffer and converts them into mxArray (matrix) output. See [How to implement a circular buffer of cv::Mat objects (OpenCV)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9472880/1121420). Circular buffer will need to be made thread safe, see [Thread safe implementation of circular buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743605/thread-safe-implementation-of-circular-buffer).

Comment: Here I am exactly two years later trying to do the same thing.  Were you ever able to accomplish this?

Comment: @KyleWright I'm in the same position. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Since MATLAB R2015a it's become very easy with the function *ipcam*:

```
cam = ipcam('http://172.28.17.193/video.mjpeg', 'admin', 'password');
% preview the camera
preview(cam);

% close preview
closepreview(cam);

% Or get a snapshop...
img = snapshot(cam);
imshow(img);

% release camera
clear cam;
```

The first time you call that function MATLAB may prompt you to download it. 
The good news is that solution doesn't even require a license to the camera acquisition toolbox.