# How to implement a circular buffer of cv::Mat objects (OpenCV)?

Tags: c++, opencv, buffer, circular-buffer

I'm trying to implement a circular buffer for my program. The buffer is used to share data between two threads as shown below. I use OpenCV to grab video frames from camera (Thread 1). Then I would like to store this data in a circular buffer, so that Thread 2 can get the data from the buffer.

[image]

How can I implement a circular buffer for `cv::Mat` objects in C++? I know how to create circular buffer for standard C++ objects (like `int` or `char`) but I can't make it work with objects of type `cv::Mat`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What difficulty are you having with the cv::Mat portion of the problem? How does that data type change the task of writing a circular buffer?

Comment: @RobKennedy I included the code that I'm having problems with. I used http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer as example and modified it to store data of cv::Mat type (instead of type 'int') but now the code throws a run-time error. Thank you.

Comment: The circular buffer code itself works fine for me (MSVC 2010 Ultimate SP1), which means your crash is cause by something OpenCV related, which you would probably be best off using a debugger to find.

Comment: Is this the actual code that's crashing? I don't see threads here.

Comment: In `cbWrite` shouldn't the check be for `cb->end==cb->size` (to reset `cb->end = 0` to avoid buffer overruns?  I realize this probably isn't what is leading to the crash but it still looks dangerous.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, this is the actual code that's crashing and the code does not have threads yet (just want to get the code working without threads first). Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Necrolis. You may be right, the circular buffer code worked fine for me too for int data types. I checked to make sure that 'elem.value' contains correct data. I think this might have something to do with the way OpenCV stores frames in cv::Mat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved, see
[Thread safe implementation of circular buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9743605/1121420)

Answer (score 3):

Whats wrong with just a vector and an index to the next slot to write to and the next one to process?

All you have to handle is the wrap around when you get to the end, and if you use a power of 2 in the vector size you can use a simple mask for that.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this tomorrow.

Comment: @Alex, using a vector will certainly simplify the code but I don't think it will fix your error. Be certain to size the vector to the capacity of the circular buffer before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

A circular buffer is thread-safe when only the writing thread updates the `end` pointer and only the reading thread updates the `start` pointer, and accesses to those pointers are atomic. You have a spot in `cbWrite` that updates `start` which will lead to a race condition.

Comment: The sample code (that's crashing) does not have threads yet. Thanks for the tip though; implementing threads will be my next step.