# Extracting stream from IP camera into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video-streaming, tcp, ip-camera

I have an IP camera that can be accessed easily using its IP address and a web browser. My project involves extracting that stream from the IP webpage into my Matlab GUI and analyzing it frame by frame. The first and easiest method was using the `imread` method:

```
 url = 'http://192.168.1.2:80/jpg/image.jpg?timestamp=';
 image  = imread(url);
 fh = image(ss);
 while(1)
  image  = imread(url);
  set(fh,'CData',image);
  drawnow;
end
```

This method has one BIG disadvantage, it reads in the stream really slow (about 1 fps) and the actual stream is streaming at 30fps.

Another method to extract the stream and link it to my Matlab GUI, I thought of extracting HTML Tags of the webpage using a TCP/IP object but I've looked around a lot and found nothing. Is there any OTHER way around it? Any help would be appreciated.

P.S I asked around at the MATLAB Newsgroup but no one seems to know a solution for that problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB - capturing video streams (MJPEG, rtsp, mpeg)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669865/matlab-capturing-video-streams-mjpeg-rtsp-mpeg)

Comment: I considered the 'mmread' option, but i am not sure if it can actually get the stream from the IP camera. what would be the correct syntax ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I livestream using an IP camera in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522255/how-do-i-livestream-using-an-ip-camera-in-matlab)