# How do I livestream using an IP camera in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, stream, camera, ip, live-streaming

How can I interface an IP camera in Matlab? I am using an IP55 from Compro technology.

We have tried the code involving the following:

```
url = '(IPaddressOfCamera)/snapshot.jpg';
ss = imread(url);
preview(ss);
```

In summary, I am trying to live stream using an IP camera with a Matlab interface. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get with your sample code?

Comment: Hi Daniel,

We don't get an error.

It's just not giving the output we need.

I believe it is just a snapshot, we are after for our IP camera to be able to live stream in Matlab for image processing.

Comment: @MatlabAsker: that's probably because the URL you give points to a snapshot (static image) rather than a live stream (video)...What the correct live stream URL is depends on camera make and model, and is often described in your camera's user manual. Voting to close as this does not seem to be a programming problem.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis We can run the IP camera perfectly, the problem is that we can't use it with the codes in Matlab that has color detection. We need to be able to do it with Live-stream

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, you would need `mjpegStreamer.cgi`

Here is the [description](https://code.google.com/p/ispyconnect/source/browse/trunk/iSpyApplication/XML/Sources.xml?r=19):

```
<Manufacturer name="Compro">
    <url version="IP350" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="JPEG" url="snapshot.jpg" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP50/70" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="JPEG" url="snapshot.jpg" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP530" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="JPEG" url="snapshot.jpg" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP540" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="JPEG" url="snapshot.jpg" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP55/60" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="JPEG" url="snapshot.jpg" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP570" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="JPEG" url="snapshot.jpg" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="NC150/420/500" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="JPEG" url="snapshot.jpg" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP350" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="MJPEG" url="mjpegStreamer.cgi" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP50/70" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="MJPEG" url="mjpegStreamer.cgi" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP530" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="MJPEG" url="mjpegStreamer.cgi" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP540" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="MJPEG" url="mjpegStreamer.cgi" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP55/60" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="MJPEG" url="mjpegStreamer.cgi" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP570" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="MJPEG" url="mjpegStreamer.cgi" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="NC150/420/500" confirmed="false" prefix="http://" Source="MJPEG" url="mjpegStreamer.cgi" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
    <url version="IP70" confirmed="false" prefix="rtsp://" Source="VLC" url="medias[CHANNEL]" AudioModel="" port="" flags="" cookies=""/>
</Manufacturer>
```