# MJPEG network stream to OpenCV 2

Tags: opencv, networking, stream, mjpeg

Can anyone explain to me why this code below does not work?

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;

    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "http://hg55.no-ip.org/mjpg/video.mjpg";
    //Yes, this stream does work! Try to paste it into your browser...

    //open the video stream and make sure it's opened
    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey();
        }
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }   
}
```

This code does cannot open the stream...

The code is based on some code in this thread: [OpenCV with Network Cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras)

The OpenCV 1 code here works without any problem for me.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Are you building OpenCV, or using prebuilt binaries?  What platform are you running on?

Comment: I'm using the prebuild binaries for Visual Studio 2010. OpenCV version 2.3.1. Windows 7, x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create a new project with Visual Studio 2010 and **OpenCV 2.2**, instead of OpenCV 2.3.1.

This solved all my problems!

Comment: Some prebuilt openCV binariess might not contain the network stream libs

Comment: Hi, I've got exactly the same problem with 2.4.3. : I can even open AVI files but not public URLs of cameras such as `http://66.184.211.231/mjpg/video.mjpg`. What could I do, should I recompile the library with a specific support, install another library, simply copy DLLs (that would be lovely)... ?