# how to get video from ip camera using emgucv

Tags: emgucv, ip-camera

**Summary:**

I'm trying to get video from IP camera in emgu, I could display video in the browser from an ip like "http://169.254.255.253".

**Question:**

How could I display this from emgu?

Comment: i just know that using httpWebRequest is the good way to get jpeg stream image from my panasonic ccty camera, but in motionJpegStream , how can i get video, because the content type of the motion jpeg is multiPart!!!!

Comment: What is your OS? Do you see this camera on your Operating System's Device Manager? I mean, can you access that directly from OS?

Comment: i'm using windows 7, yes I see it on my os using this link: http://192.168.1.253/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=320x240&Quality=Standard

Comment: OK, see this post: http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3095#p6615 You can get your system cameras list with DriectShow dll. If access ip camera with using DirectShow, may be, you can define your ip camera to capture object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Capture _Capture = new Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateFileCapture("http://username:pass@cam_address/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480&req_fps=30&.mjpg");
```

I didn't test but may be this code snippet or approach can help you. For OpenCV example you can examine this page: [OpenCV with Network Cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras)

And you can examine this method's wiki page: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/a26a5e9d-53d7-633a-5d50-508aa22dd1fd.htm

Comment: thank you, but your code doesn't work properly, cvCreateFileCapture return IntPtr. so i use that like : IntPtr i = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCreateFileCapture("http://192.168.1.253/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=320x240&Quality=Standard"); but I don't know how to get video from url?!!

Comment: OK, Normally capture object can get int param. Int param means is index of camera on your system. For example if you use like this "Capture _Capture = New Capture(0);" you define your system camera which index number is zero. See this page for more detail: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/0f3099f2-d381-4319-6b31-6c289fb1e744.htm

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Emgu 3.1 then try this:

```
Capture cameraCapture
cameraCapture = new Capture("http://user:passwd@http://169.254.255.253");
Mat frame = cameraCapture.QueryFrame();
imageBox1.Image = frame;
```

here is the Capture Class Reference:

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/5edc4ff8-cec3-c5ee-8e62-629cf4c7940a.htm

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

via rstp protocol you can get the video feed

```
grabber = new Capture(@"rtsp://UserName:Password@172.198.8.44:654/Streaming/Channels/101") 
grabber.QueryFrame();
```

this is for Hikvision camera