# IP Camera integration in Emgu Capture

Tags: c#, video, emgucv, capture, ip-camera

I want to capture video stream from an ip. I've seen this but the type name cvCreateFileCapture does not exist on cvInvoke in Emgu 3.0 is there any way I can capture video from an ip?

I've tried using this, it didn't work but the message box shows which means capture is not null. imageCamera is empty

```
 _capture = new Capture("http://uname:pass@10.16.33.158/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi");here
 if (_capture != null) //if camera capture has been successfully created
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Capture success");
            _capture.ImageGrabbed += ProcessFrame;
            _capture.Start();
        }

 _capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
 Image<Bgra, Byte> newFrame = new Image<Bgra, Byte>(frame.Bitmap);
 imageCamera.Image = newFrame;
```

I entered this http://uname:pass@10.16.33.158/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi in my browser and the video stream is there.

I've seen I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144527/how-to-get-video-from-ip-camera-using-emgucv/10148816#10148816)  but the type name cvCreateFileCapture does not exist on cvInvoke in Emgu 3.0 is there any way I can capture video from an ip?

Tried entering http://uname:pass@10.16.33.158/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi into VLC -> Media -> Network stream, it works perfectly. But why I can't see it on my capture?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve() requires you to use Grab() first. You can also try using QueryFrame() instead if you just need the one image.

```
var image = _capture.QueryFrame();
```

Comment: I can use the Retrieve() properly with a video from a file. The problem is setting the capture from a IP Camera feed. Not getting an image

Comment: @Untitled might be that Opencv don't understand the .cgi link. Looking at this [post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17210/d-link-ip-cam-read-stream-and-picture/), try add ?x.mjpeg to the url after .cgi