# opencv capture network camera

Tags: opencv

How can i capture my network camera frame for opencv,if i don't know my model of camera ?
e.g I can watch the network camera  in 
`http://192.168.1.25` but i can't use `CvCapture *capture = cvCreateFileCapture("rtsp://192.168.1.25");` to capture my camera in opencv

I found some way to use while i know the model of camera.
So I must to know my model of camera? or any way to capture my camera in opencv?

sorry my english is poor,but i need to know network camera how to use in opencv ...
thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV with Network Cameras](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras)

Comment: I have tried this way,but I can't capture any frame..