# After reading multiple frames from a camera, OpenCV suddenly always fails to read frames. How do I diagnose this?

Tags: opencv

I run a program similar to the one in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8719192/26070

```
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

#include <iostream>

/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cv::VideoCapture vcap;
    cv::Mat image;

    const std::string videoStreamAddress = "rtsp://192.0.0.1:8081/live.sdp";

    //open the video stream and make sure it's opened
    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    for(;;) {
        if(!vcap.read(image)) {
            std::cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
            cv::waitKey(500);
        } else {
            cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
        }
        if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
    }
}
```

The program runs fine for a certain amount of time (about one minute or so) and then the call to read() (method from cv::VideoCapture) always returns `false`.

The output is as follows:

```
[mpeg4 @ 00da27a0] ac-tex damaged at 22 7
[mpeg4 @ 00da27a0] Error at MB: 309
No frame
No frame
No frame
```

Note: the first two lines are not always present.

So, how can I determine what the root of the problem is?