# Error while capturing video via RTSP from a network camera using OpenCV and FFMPEG

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am using OpenCV and FFMPEG to capture frames from a network camera using RTSP. The point is that OpenCV successfully loads the FFMPEG .dll but icvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG_p returns false in the following code of cap_ffmpeg.cpp:

```
virtual bool open( const char* filename )
{
    close();

    icvInitFFMPEG();
    if( !icvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG_p )
        return false;
    ffmpegCapture = icvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG_p( filename );
    return ffmpegCapture != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the stream is not ready or you have problems with the network address/access. 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras) if you have followed the correct way of doing it. Try pining the network resource first and see if it is available or not. The camera also must allow un-authenticated access, set via its web interface. Sometimes MJPEG works and MPEG4 has problems.

Comment: The stream is ready since I am connected using VLC with the same exactly path.

Comment: Does the stream play on VLC? if it does, make sure the data being sent to OpenCV is in a supported format.

Comment: Yes it does, and VLC uses ffmpeg (x264) via live555, so I think OpenCV does the same.

Comment: I don't believe VLC uses live555 , just ffmpeg and I openCV has an interface highGUI that does not use live 555 either. the udp port 554 could be blocked.

Comment: Dear Michelle, VLC does use live555. Just capture packets using Wireshark and you will see what VLC says in the RTSP handshake ;-)

Port 554 is not blocked since my firewall is set to off. OpenCV loads the dll of FFMPEG returning a successful pointer to icvCreateFileCapture_FFMPEG_p but when calling the function it returns always 0 (NULL). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but you can optionally enable vlc --enable-live555 \
Not sure whats parts it uses because I know vlc can work with just ffmpeg selected. So maybe I am partially wrong, but live555 is not all that good anyway, I know c++ very well but even for us its difficult to build a halfway decent client with that library