# IP camera video streaming using openCV in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, ip-camera

I have never written VC++ apps and now  i am assigned a task of capturing IP camera and saving as files on the harddisk.

i was surfing for last 2 days but cant find any suitable link or code for the same.

the sample code i found on the net, captures webcam but nothing relevent to reading video streams on rtsp protocols with credentials.

please help me for this..
Thanks & Regards

Comment: just pass the url to VideoCapture::open(), and use VideoWriter for saving it

Comment: @berak how to pass credentials along with url

Comment: Could some body pass on me the document to study this.

Comment: Can you use some finished software? For example VLC player should be able to grab the IP Camera stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below is the code snippet which accesses a public ip camera, which works fine for me.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("video", 1);
    VideoCapture cap("http://66.184.211.231/mjpg/video.mjpg");
    while ( cap.isOpened() )
    {
        cap >> frame;
        if(frame.empty()) break;

        imshow("video", frame);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here are few link for your reference [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450102/cvvideocapture-works-for-webcams-but-not-ip-cameras) [link 2](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3664/ip-network-camera-access/)

Comment: The code you gave din't work, can you please tell what code be the possible problem. It works for my IP camera setup on LAN.

Comment: @Mayur Can you breif your problem? Doesnt work in which scenario? If you cant explain in comments create it as a seperate question. Thanks.

Comment: The code din't work in case when I am trying to access a public IP camera. When am trying to open IP camera on my LAN network am able to.

Comment: @Mayur Sorry I am not sure or guess what might be the reason.