# How to read live feed using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, video, feed, live

I am trying to read live feed using OpenCV, I previously used read videos which were already converted to .avi , but how does it work IF I try to read a live feed which is in raw format ?

Comment: Study ffmpeg. OpenCV is one layer above.

Comment: what is your live feed actually ? are you talking about a webcam ? an mjpg stream ?

Comment: As @berak said if it is for mjpg from IP cam you can see my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892370/ip-camera-video-streaming-using-opencv-in-vc/18894735#18894735

Comment: @berak - Live feed is in raw format - and its a USB camera.

Answer (score 4):

oh, easy then:

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0); // open camera 0, or /dev/video0

VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("/home/me/my.avi"); // a video file

VideoCapture cap;
cap.open("http://dummy.url?stream=mpeg"); // a mjpeg , ipcam stream


// whatever, from here on you get a 'raw' 24bit bgr stream:
if ( cap.isOpened() ) {
    Mat frame;
    if ( ! cap.read(frame) ) // end of stream
         return -1; 
}
```