# Imageprocessing from an RTSP stream

Tags: c++, opencv, frame, rtsp

Hi so my plan was to Process some Images with OpenCV which I got from an RTSP stream.

So I'm using livemedia555 library for getting the Frames but now somehow I dont know what to do with those Frames anymore.

I got 2 different cams one stream mpeg-2 and the other mpeg-4

hope someone could give me a hint how i get Images out of those Frames now.

Comment: Why don't you use OpenCV library to grab frames from the stream? Here's an example on how to use VideoCapture class to capture frames from an rtsp stream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras/8719192#8719192

Comment: ya I know that will be my next try if i dont get it working. but much more, I want an answer what i could do with the frames i got. and how I could use those Frames i have for further processing.

Comment: So essentially you need to figure out how to convert from livemedia555 image data type to OpenCV Mat? I'm not familiar with livemedia555 library.

Comment: I dont think its any specific image data type. that should just be the frames as far as i know. i also tryed that code you linked but i just get the Error opening stream or file message.

Comment: it must have a data type. how else would a library store frames? It could store them in an array, it could be some data type specific to the library.For example OpenCV stores frame data in `Mat` class (or data type).

Comment: ya it stores the data in an uint8 array but openCV does not know what it should do with them get the (-206 Error) . I get frames of different size periodically so what Google told me about that is that those are I/P -Frames so those frames are not images themself those are just compressd datas of those images if im not wrong.

Comment: maybe use your library to decode the images first. Sorry I can't help you with livemedia555 library related questions.