# DirectShow filter for ip-camera

Tags: c++, opencv, directshow, ip-camera

I need to write DirectShow filter which will stream data from ip camera. I have found [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras) how to open ip camera stream using opencv.
I have only basic knowledges how to write a directShow filters. What should I do to send data from one directShow filter to another?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check Push source filter sample from Windows SDK.

Also some open source and coomercial implementations available:

MJPEG HTTP from Alax.info (source available) - http://alax.info/blog/1216
VisioForge MJPEG / MPEG-4 / H264 via HTTP / RTSP / RTMP (commercial) - [Video Capture SDK](http://www.visioforge.com/video-capture-sdk-net2.html) or [Filter SDK](http://www.visioforge.com/rtsp-rtmp-http-directshow-filter.html)

Good idea to start from Alax project, but use FFMPEG like VisioForge for demuxing / decoding.

Comment: also found another open source project, sorry, don't use it like Alax or VisioForge, but looks as good start point too - [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/)

Comment: Thank you. I found it very useful. I wrote a direct-show filter for AXIS ip-camera which streams MJPEG. I want to decompress this stream using MJPEG Decompressor, but I always get a black screen on MJPEG Decompressor output. Can it be that MJPEG Decompressor cannot decompress video that I send from my ip-camera source filter?

Comment: try to decompress each frame using GDI+ for example, to be sure that JPEG frames are correct, also you can implement JPEG decompression in your filter and produce output in RGB24 (or YUV if required).