# JAVA RTSP Opening IP Cam failed on 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, authorization, rtsp

Morning,

i have problem with opening stream at my IP Cam D-Link DSC-935L. All works good in VLC, but when i try open stream at Java over the OpenCV (with opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll) & VideoCapture - i get only this error:

> [rtsp @ 000000002defd160] method DESCRIBE failed: 401 Unauthorized

My code snippet

```
videoCapture = new VideoCapture();
videoCapture.open("rtsp://admin@10.0.0.20:554/upceSource.mjpg");

if (!videoCapture.isOpened()) {
    System.out.println("FAILED");
}else{
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

How i can pass username by another way? I have no password set.

Login: admin

Password: **unused**

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Based on what i [read online](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712998/opencv-with-network-cameras), it should be possible to authenticate like this. Did you try setting some dummy password and trying it with that? Maybe it's having issues because of the lack of password?